# How to compute additional statistics in Evaluator?

Tags: tfx

In the TFX Evaluator, on top of the metrics described in TFMA format,I would like to compute statistics relative to the performance of my model on my dataset. Naturally, I would also like a way to get access to these statistics: either through the output of the component, or by letting the component upload the statistics somewhere.

I guess that some amount of custom code would be needed (both for the computation and the return of the statistics), but I don't really know how much and what would be the best way to write it. Any ideas on the topic ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods that you can achieve this depending on how you see the placement of your functionality in the TFX flow.

1. Writing a Custom TFX Components -  which requires a lot of effort and you need to define quite a few things.
2. Reusing Existing Components - instead of writing a component for TFX entirely from scratch, we can inherit an existing component and customize it by overwriting the executor functionality.

I would suggest the following blogs to begin with:
[Anatomy of TFX Component](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/understanding_custom_components)
[Creating custom Components](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/01/creating-custom-tfx-component.html)

Comment: https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/09/creating-custom-tfx-executor_19.html blog for creating custom Executor